# How to select only string (non-numeric) columns when there are mixed type columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a data frame with three columns with dtypes (`object`, `int`, and `float`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, np.nan, 5],
    'col2': [3, 4, 5, 4],
    'col3': ['This is a text column'] * 4
})
```

I need to replace the `np.nan` with `None`, which is an object (since `None` becomes to NULL when imported to PostgresSQL).

```
df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
```

I think (correct me if I'm wrong) `None` cannot be used in any NumPy/Pandas array except for arrays with dtype `object`. And so 'col1' above becomes an `object` column after `replace`. Now, if I wanted to subset only the string columns (which in this case should only be 'col3'), I can no longer use `df.select_dtypes(include=object)`, which returns all `object` dtype columns, including 'col1'. I've been working around this by using this *hacky* solution:

```
# Select only object columns, which includes 'col1'
(df.select_dtypes(include=object)
   # Hack, after this, 'col1' becomes float again since None becomes np.nan
   .apply(lambda col: col.apply(lambda val: val))
   # Now select only the object columns
   .select_dtypes(include=object))
```

I'm wondering if there are idiomatic (or less hacky) ways to accomplish this. The use case really arose since I need to get the string columns from a data frame where there are numeric (`float` or `int`) columns with missing values represented by `None` rather than `np.nan`.

**Another solution**

Based on Mayank Porwal's solution below:

```
# The list comprehension returns a boolean list
df.loc[:, [pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').isna().all() for col in df.columns.tolist()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample df, you can do something like this:

After replacing `np.nan` to `None`, `col1` becomes an `object`:

```
In [1413]: df.dtypes
Out[1413]: 
col1    object
col2     int64
col3    object
dtype: object
```

To pick the columns which contains only strings, you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` and check if the column contains all `Nan` using `isna`:

```
In [1416]: cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()
In [1422]: cols
Out[1422]: ['col1', 'col3']

In [1424]: for i in cols:
      ...:     if pd.to_numeric(df[i], errors='coerce').isna().all():
      ...:         print(f'{i}: String col')
      ...:     else:
      ...:         print(f'{i}: number col')
      ...: 
col1: number col
col3: String col
```

Comment: I like this. Nice use of the `coerce` argument in `pd.to_numeric()`. Definitely more robust and idiomatic. And it fits well into the framework of my function for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your 2 operations:

1. Extract `object` columns and process them.
2. Convert `NaN` to `None` before export to pgsql.

```
>>> df.dtypes
col1    float64
col2      int64
col3     object
dtype: object

# Step 1: process string columns
>>> df.update(df.select_dtypes('object').agg(lambda x: x.str.upper()))

# Step 2: replace nan by None
>>> df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)

>>> df
   col1  col2                   col3
0   1.0     3  THIS IS A TEXT COLUMN
1   2.0     4  THIS IS A TEXT COLUMN
2  None     5  THIS IS A TEXT COLUMN
3   5.0     4  THIS IS A TEXT COLUMN
```